# Plot a factorial function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello I want to plot a graph for of n! since I'm working with O(n!) time complexity. How can I make this look smooth? Preferably I want to show the marks. I tried doing plotting the first 10 factorials. If there is better way to display operations per element that would be helpful too.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={O(n!) Scaling data input},
  xlabel={Elements},
  ylabel={Operations},
  xmin=0, xmax=25,
  ymin=0, ymax=3628800,
  xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10},
  ytick={0,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,632880,3628800},
  legend pos=north west,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  ]  
\addplot[
  color=blue,
  mark=square,
  ]
coordinates {
   (0,1)(1,1)(2,2)(3,6)(4,24)(5,120)(6,720)(7,5040)(8,40320)(9,632880)(10,3628800)
};
\legend{O(n!)}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: :(]

Comment: Could you use a semilog?

Comment: Note that a factorial is a special case of the Gamma function, i.e. $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, but the Gamma function can also do fractions.  So just plot the Gamma function.

Comment: So a Gamma function as a semilog with log on y axis?

Comment: Are you plotting something where the result makes sense for non-integer *n*? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to join the points.

Comment: @J.Kirk.: sure.

Comment: No @cfr. I just can't figure out how to make the y scale log .. can someone propose a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to use `semilogyaxis`, for example:

[image: semilogyaxis demonstration]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            title={O(n!) Scaling data input},
            xlabel={Elements},
            ylabel={Operations},
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            ymin=0, ymax=3628800,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10},
            ytick={0,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,632880,3628800},
            legend pos=north west,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            only marks,
            mark=square,
        ]
        coordinates {
                (0,1)(1,1)(2,2)(3,6)(4,24)(5,120)(6,720)(7,5040)(8,40320)(9,632880)(10,3628800)
            };
        \legend{O(n!)}
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the other answer you might want to use a semilogarithmic axis.  Using the FFI of LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3), you can also plot the Gamma function alongside, as you wanted to have a "smooth factorial function".

Also I corrected your typo in 9! (it's 362880 instead of 632880).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\directlua{
  ffi=require("ffi")
  ffi.cdef[[
  double tgamma(double x);
  ]]
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Gamma}{1}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \directlua{tex.print(ffi.C.tgamma(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1}))}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    title={$O(n!)$ Scaling data input},
    xlabel={Elements},
    ylabel={Operations},
    domain=0:10,
    ytick={0,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800},
    log ticks with fixed point,
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]  
    \addplot+[mark=square,only marks] coordinates {
      (0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,6) (4,24) (5,120) (6,720) (7,5040)
      (8,40320) (9,362880) (10,3628800)
    };
    \addlegendentry{$O(n!)$}

    \addplot+[no marks,samples=100] {Gamma(x+1)};
    \addlegendentry{$\Gamma(n+1)$}

  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to use straight lines to connect the data? The parabola (?) between the first two data points now suggests a decrease followed by an increase.

Comment: @Karlo No, that is correct.  This is what the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) looks like.

Answer (score 3):

As cmhughes already stated in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371849/954419), the key is to use a logarithmic y axis.

This answer is just to show how else you could have created your graph by *calculating* the values instead of giving them explicitly. In contrast to the answer of [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371899/95441) here the values are only calculated for the integer x values, but therefor it can be done by LaTeX itself, so without the need of using FFI of LuaJITTeX.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat` level to use the advanced positioning features of the axis labels
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % use log y-axis
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        title={$O(n!)$ Scaling data input},
        xlabel={Elements},
        ylabel={Operations},
        % so you don't have to state the values manually
        % (the data of the first given plot (only) are used)
        xtick=data,
        ytick=data,
        % you can also use ...
        enlargelimits=false,
%        % ... instead of giving the limits explicitly
%        xmin=0, xmax=10,
%        ymin=0, ymax=3628800,
        legend pos=north west,
        legend cell align=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        only marks,
    ]
        % automatic calculation of $n!$
        % (I placed it before the "manual" variant so that the right yticks are shown)
        \addplot [
            red,
            mark=*,
            mark size=1.5pt,
            % state the domain where the values should be calculated
            domain=0:10,
            % state the number of samples that should be calculated
            samples=11,
        ] {x!};
        % typo at $9!$ (switched first two digits)
        \addplot [color=blue,mark=square] coordinates {
            (0,1)(1,1)(2,2)(3,6)(4,24)(5,120)(6,720)(7,5040)(8,40320)(9,632880)(10,3628800)
        };

        \legend{
            $O(n!)$ (calculated),
            $O(n!)$ (by hand),
        }
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]