# How to plot this modified Bessel function?

Tags: plot

I'm new to TeX and I wish to plot in my master's dissertation the graph of the function $E_2:\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus{0} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

`$$E_2(x,y)= (2 \pi)^{-1}K_0(\sqrt(x²+y²)), $$`

Where `K_0` is the modified Bessel function of second kind of order 0.

Edit:

I have added graphical renderings  to make it easier to grasp the purpose of the TeX code above.  To get the \sqrt function displayed, I used braces in place of the parentheses in the code above.  To get the "where" clause to work, i used $ signs in place of the backquotes (`).  The use of \setminus does not seem to me to be mathematically correct, but I have not changed it since I do not know the  author's intent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Probably cannot (as in cannot do it in a reasonable time). Use Python/Mathematica/whatever to generate a list of (x, y) coordinates, then plot it in TikZ.

Comment: The alternative is to use shell-escape or ffi etc. to avoid hard coding (might need shell escape however). See [pgfmath - Erf function in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107423/erf-function-in-latex) / [tikz pgf - Plot a factorial function - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371255/plot-a-factorial-function) for examples.

Comment: Special function are not defined in PGF. The simplest and most TeXish solution could be to use the `gnuplot` mode for TikZ plot, as recent version of gnuplot define them (needs installed gnuplot and compile with shell-escape). Behind the scene does what @user202729 suggested in his/her first comment.

Comment: It is fairly easy to format a file of data points (plus a header of column names) compatible with pgfplots.  See also pgfplotstable for delimiter options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer algebra system (CAS), Sage, knows about [Bessel functions](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/bessel.html) and, through the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) package it can calculate the points that LaTeX needs to plot with the `tikz` package.

I don't have experience with the Bessel function, so after reading the documentations I went to a [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to see what the result should look like. Copy/paste the code below into the Sage Cell server:

```
var('x,y')
f = (1/(2*pi))*Bessel(0,type='K')(sqrt(x^2+y^2))
plot3d(f,(x,-20,20),(y,-20,20))
#plot3d(f,(x,-20,20),(y,-20,20),aspect_ratio=[1,1,25])
```

and press `Evaluate` then you will get a plot that, if you reach in and rotate it, will look something like:
[image]

Now remove the hashtag before line 4 and add a hashtag before line 3. Press `Evaluate`, rotate the plot, and you can get something like this:
[image]

In summary, the accurate plot will have a small height and playing with the aspect ratio will show useful detail.

With that in mind the LaTeX code below will plot the modified Bessel function.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
var('x,y')
minX = -20
maxX = 20
minY = -20
maxY = 20
xcoords = [i for i in srange(minX,maxX,1)]
ycoords = [i for i in srange(minY,maxY,1)]
f = (1/(2*pi))*Bessel(0,type='K')(sqrt(x^2+y^2))

output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[view={20}{45},xmin=%d, xmax=%d, ymin=%d, ymax=%d]"%(minX,maxX,minY,maxY)
output += r"\addplot3[colormap/viridis,surf,opacity=0.5,mesh/rows=%d] coordinates {"%(len(ycoords))
# the length of ycoords is the number of y values
for y in ycoords:
    for x in xcoords:
        output += r"(%f, %f, %f) "%(x,y,f(x=x,y=y))

output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

We know this plot has exaggerated the z-axis. This can be corrected to what you want by forcing a maximum z value. For example, I added `zmax=2` on line 18 to get:
[image]

Sage is not part of LaTeX so you will either have to download it from the Sagemath site or open up a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. With the Cocalc account you can be up and running in 5-10 minutes; all you need to do is create a LaTeX document, copy/paste the code in, and press the `Build` button.

**EDIT:** With respect to your comment below, there are several methods for getting .png output. With Sage, it's trivial. The picture from the Sage Cell server has an "i" in a circle to the bottom right of the picture.
If you left click on it, a menu opens up with an option to create a .png.
[image]

With respect to LaTeX, you can get a similar look with the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
var('x,y')
minX = -7
maxX = 7
minY = -7
maxY = 7
xcoords = [i for i in srange(minX,maxX,.5)]
ycoords = [i for i in srange(minY,maxY,.5)]
f = (1/(2*pi))*Bessel(0,type='K')(sqrt(x^2+y^2))

output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[hide axis,view={20}{45},xmin=%d, xmax=%d, ymin=%d, ymax=%d]"%(minX,maxX,minY,maxY)
output += r"\addplot3[surf,fill=white,faceted color = black,opacity=0.7,mesh/rows=%d] coordinates {"%(len(ycoords))
# the length of ycoords is the number of y values
for y in ycoords:
    for x in xcoords:
        output += r"(%f, %f, %f) "%(x,y,f(x=x,y=y))

output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

You'll have to play around with the code to get the look you want. The pdf can be converted to png via an external program, such as [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, the graph that I need is exactly like this one I constructed in sagemath: `var('x,y')
f = (1/(2*pi))*bessel_K(0, sqrt(x^2+y^2))
#plot3d(f,(x,-20,20),(y,-20,20),color='white',opacity=0.7,frame=False, mesh=True)
plot3d(f,(x,-7,7),(y,-7,7),aspect_ratio=[1,1,25],color='white',opacity=0.7,frame=False, mesh=True)`  It is possible to generate and png file with this graphics or to use cocalc to generate something in this style?

Comment: @VictorRafael : Yes. See the edit I added to my answer (above) for details.