# Is there an easy way to plot Jacobi Elliptic Functions with Tikz-PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, function

So The Jacobi Elliptic Functions are a little bit tricky to plot because they depend on the complete elliptic integral of the first kind `K(k)` that can be written as a sum of double factorials, and the Fourier series for the Jacobi Elliptic Functions then depend on exponentials of these elliptic integrals, I can easily write all the mathematical formulas, but I don't know an easy way to represent them on Tikz or PGF, probably gnuplot would be the easiest but I would like to make it depend only on Tikz PGF because of configurations problems I am having with gnuplot, and I would like to write that in a formulaic form, instead of a table because I would like to change a parameter easily from one compilation to another.

Basically, is there a way to calculate summations and double factorials in Tikz - PGF on some variables and then use them in a plot of a function that will depend on those ?

Bassically I need a way of calculating:

```
K(k) = pi/2 sum[n=0:10] ((( 2 * n - 1)!!)/((2 * n)!!)) * (k^(2*n))
```

and for a given `u` and `v= sqrt(1-u^2)`

```
q = exp(-pi * (K(v)/K(u)))
```

calculate and plot for example:

```
sn_u(x) = (2* pi/(K(u) * u)) * sum[n=0:5] (((q^(n+0.5)) * sin((2*n+1) * x * pi/(2 * K(u))))/(1-(q^(2n+1))))
```

How do I implement these sums and double factorial as a function? Also is there a way to make these calculations modular in the way I wrote them?

Comment: this image is a true or false example about your `sn_u(x)`, https://imgur.com/rXpzMTX.

Comment: It seems about right, but 0.5 is a boring value for u, it is too much like a sin function, a u=0.95 is the interesting one.

Comment: https://imgur.com/TJwWe3s

Comment: Jacobi elliptic functions are defined in Sage, [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/jacobi.html). This can be accessed with the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) package and the output can be forced through tikz/pgf in the similar fashion to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647902/how-to-plot-this-modified-bessel-function/647986#647986) post on modified Bessel functions. It sounds like this would address your concern with gnuplot.I'm not sure of your parameters in jacobi('sn', ?, ?) but it seems like it would be straightforward.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 yes, looks like you got it to work, I don't know if you put more terms in the sums but the approximation is very good. Here is a Desmos graph with all of the functions, but if you could answer how did you do for sn I can modify it easily for the other functions.

Comment: @DJP I will look at that if I have to, but I fell that if I were able to just use Tikz-PGF it would be better and simpler, those parameters are from the Fourier representation of `sn(x,u)` that converges "fast" and "uniformily". The Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kuymi4vh3k , sorry.

Comment: I have an Asymptote package with the Jacobi theta functions: [gist](https://gist.github.com/stla/a5f67c6b33062f88cc37588171688424#file-jacobi-asy). You can derive the Jacobi elliptic functions from the functions provided by the package.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell more because my mathematical ability is limited.

The following incompleted code, in [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/), can be compiled on  http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/.

```
import graph;
import gsl; // https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/gsl.cc
// 1086 addGSLDOUBLEFunc<gsl_sf_ellint_Kcomp>(SYM(K),SYM(k));
// in asy code, it is 'real K(real k)'
// for gsl_sf_ellint_Kcomp, see 
// https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html?highlight=bessel#c.gsl_sf_ellint_Kcomp and 
// https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html?highlight=gsl_prec_double#c.gsl_mode_t.GSL_PREC_DOUBLE

size(350,200,false);

real q(real k){ return exp(-pi*(K(sqrt(1-k^2))/K(k)));}

typedef real newreal(real);

// Define the function "sn_u(real k, int n)"
newreal sn_u(real k, int n){
  return new real(real x)
  {
    real createfunction(int n)
    {
      return ((q(k)^(n+0.5)) * sin((2*n+1) * x * pi/(2 * K(k))))/(1-(q(k)^(2n+1)));
    }
    return (2*pi)/(K(k)*k)*sum(sequence(createfunction,n));
  // See T[] sequence(T f(int), int n) and T sum(T[] a)
  // in 6.12 Arrays of the documentation.
  };
}

// the graph
guide g=graph(sn_u(0.95,6),-10,10,350);
draw(g);

label("$u=0.95$, n from 0 to 5",(5,0.5));

// for axes
xaxis(Label("$x$",position = EndPoint, align=NE),
      xmin=-10,
      Ticks(scale(.7)*Label(),
            NoZero, end=false, Step=1, Size=.8mm, size=.4mm,
            pTick=black),
            Arrow);

yaxis(Label("$y$",position = EndPoint, align=NE),
      ymin=-1,ymax=1,
      Ticks(scale(.7)*Label(),
            NoZero, begin=false, end=false, Step=1, Size=.8mm, size=.4mm,
            pTick=black),
      Arrow);
```

[image]

Comment: Can Asymptote be run by the latex compiler ? Or does it just use Latex for the image generation? Because I really would like a Tikz-PGF solution, because it would all be integrated into one enviroment.

Comment: @FelipeDilho Yes, with the package **asymptote** you can integrate some Asymptote code in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, a bit late.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
     declare function={
        K(\u) = pi/2*(1+(\u^2)/4+9*(\u^4)/64+25*(\u^6)/(16*16));
        I(\x,\i)=((e^(-(\i+0.5)*pi*K(0.3)/K(0.95)))*sin(deg((2*\i+1)*\x*pi/(2*K(0.95)))))/(1-(e^(-(2*\i+1)*pi*K(0.3)/K(0.95))));
        sn(\x)=2*pi/(0.95*K(0.95))*(I(\x,0)+I(\x,1)+I(\x,2)+I(\x,3)+I(\x,4)+I(\x,5));
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        axis equal image,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = {$y$},
        domain=-5:5,
        ymax=2,ymin=-2,
        samples=100,
        grid=major,
        ]
        \addplot [color=blue] {sn(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```